# GWT MVP with cookie and history

Tags: gwt, cookies, mvp, browser-history

I'm making a web app using GWT with the MVP.
I'm trying to use cookies and I have a problem with the History.
If a user has a cookie and logs to the web app, the app logs him automatically and that is great !!. now for some reason he has the ability to click on the backspace and return backward with history ! eventhough it was empty when he logged !!

Address when logged in : ...html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#mainpage
Address for some reason saved there and pops clicking backspace : ...html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997.

Code :

```
   public void go(HasWidgets container) {
        this.container = container;
        if (History.getToken().isEmpty()) {
            fetchCookie();

          }
          else {
            History.fireCurrentHistoryState();
          }
        }

      protected void fetchCookie()
      {
            String sessionID = Cookies.getCookie("username");
            if (sessionID == null)
            {
                History.newItem("login");
            } 

            else
            {
               .....
              }
```

Now let's say I don't care about this problem ( but I do) and try to interact with the web app after hitting backspace, I get an Exception : 
Exception caught: This widget's parent does not implement HasWidgets.

so I'll post the mainpage view that implements Composite and has a SplitLayoutPanel:

```
  Panel.add(books);
  vPanel.add(chapters);
  vPanel.add(textButton);

  splitPanel = new SplitLayoutPanel();
  assetPicPanel = new VerticalPanel();
  titleAssetPic = new Label();
  assetPicPanel.add(titleAssetPic);
  vPanel.add(assetPicPanel);

  assetVidPanel = new VerticalPanel();
  titleAssetVid = new Label();
  assetVidPanel.add(titleAssetVid);
  vPanel.add(assetVidPanel);

  assetAudioPanel = new VerticalPanel();
  titleAssetAudio = new Label();
  assetAudioPanel.add(titleAssetAudio);
  vPanel.add(assetAudioPanel);

  assetTextPanel = new VerticalPanel();
  titleAssetText = new Label();
  assetTextPanel.add(titleAssetText);
  vPanel.add(assetTextPanel);

  splitPanel.addWest(vPanel, 300);

  assetLocationPanel = new VerticalPanel();

  splitPanel.add(page);
  page.setWidth("50%");
  RootLayoutPanel rp = RootLayoutPanel.get();
  rp.add(splitPanel);
  initWidget(rp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set a cookie in `onModuleLoad()` method of your Entry point class - it runs only once when an app is loaded for the first time. There is absolutely no reason to check for this cookie on every navigation action.

If you are concerned that you may have to kick out your user while the app is still open, you should do it by throwing a LoginException from your RPC calls. You have to check for credentials on each RPC call anyway - otherwise anyone can use them even without opening your app.

Comment: Sorry, I followed the Google tutorial about the MVP, and this go(..) is for the AppController that the onModuleLoad() calls, so I think the fetchCookie() runs only once. I still didn't get why the History stack has something other than the 'mainpage' ...

Comment: It looks like this method is called on every navigation action. In either case, you should not worry about the history stack at all, because your authentication mechanism should be completely independent of navigation (e.g. it should work on page reloads, bookmarks, back and forth keys, etc.)